# Error Creating Folder in Sharepoint using Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am attempting to create a child folder in Sharepoint and I am receiving errors. I can successfully create two levels of folders, but upon creating the third level, I receive the error below:

"The request URI is not valid. The bound function binding to 'microsoft.graph.driveItem' does not support the escape function annotation."

I am using Postman and taking the steps here to create folders:

**1) Top Level: (Successful) - Folder1 Created**

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/<SITE_ID>/drive/root/children

{
  "name": "Folder1",
  "folder": { },
  "@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior": "replace"
}
```

**2) First Child (Successful - Folder2 Created within Folder1)**

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/<SITE_ID>/drive/root:/Folder1:/children

{
  "name": "Folder2",
  "folder": { },
  "@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior": "replace"
}
```

**3) Second Child (Fails)**

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/<SITE_ID>/drive/root:/Folder1:/Folder2:/children

{
  "name": "Folder3",
  "folder": { },
  "@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior": "replace"
}
```

Any feedback how to properly create the Folder3 folder would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In the last example, the error occurs since  *invalid* Url format is specified  for accessing `Folder2`  in the provided endpoint:

```
    https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/<SITE_ID>/drive/root:/Folder1:/Folder2:/children
                                                                |_________________|                                                          
                                                                       ^^^
                                                          invalid path syntax for accessing Folder2
```

To [create folder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-post-children?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) under `Folder2` sub folder, the Url format should be as follows:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/<SITE_ID>/drive/root:/Folder1/Folder2:/children
```

Refer [Addressing resources in a drive on OneDrive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/concepts/addressing-driveitems?view=odsp-graph-online) for a more details.

Answer (score 0):

```
Trying using below code. 
Where parentDriveId is root drive ID and driveId is the folder where we try to create folder. 
 
var driveItem = new DriveItem
                {
                    Name = driveName,
                    Folder = new Folder { },
                    AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>()
                       {
                          { "@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior", "rename" }
                       }
                };

createdDriveId = (await graphclient.Drives[parentDriveId].Items[driveId].Children.Request().AddAsync(driveItem)).Id;
```